# Can't see my model within backbone collection

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, model

I'm trying to add an item to a collection but first I want to remove the existing one. Only one item will ever exist. I can create a new one, just not remove one. Maybe I'm doing it backwards.

This is my collection, the changetheme is the function that gets called, which works away, but can't figure out how to remove the existing one. this.model.destroy() just throws an error. Maybe i'm out of context.

```
bb.model.Settings = Backbone.Collection.extend(_.extend({
    model:  bb.model.Setting,
    localStorage: new Store("rrr"),

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this
        this.model.bind('add', this.added, this);
    },
    changetheme: function(value) {
        var self = this
        this.destroy();
        this.create({theme:value});
    },
}));
```

If it matters this is my model

```
bb.model.Setting = Backbone.Model.extend(_.extend({
    defaults: {
        theme: 'e'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
    },
    added: function(item) {
        var self = this;
        this.destroy(); 
    },
}));
```

Comment: If it's a collection with only one item, shouldn't you just use a model?

Comment: Thats true, but I guess I just wanted to gain some experience doing the full thing.

Comment: It looks like my deletion of the collection does not commit to localstorage, as the collection is been reduced when running. I didn't think you need to commit changes to localstorage

Comment: You can get rid of all your `var self = this;` statements. The technique is only used to pass `this` to sub functions under the name of `self`, but you don't use `self` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To remove first item from collection you can call `collection.shift()`, also you can just clear collection by calling `collection.reset()`. So in your case one could write:

```
changetheme: function(value) {
    this.shift();
    this.create({theme:value});
}
```

**UPD**
Ok, let me explain - in your example localStorage plays like any other server side. So when you call "**create**", then according to [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) backbone instantiates a model with a hash of attributes, saves it to the server(localStorage), and adds to the set after being successfully created. That is why your collection items count increases on each page refresh. But when you call **shift/remove** [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-shift) then only you client side collection is affected, not the server(localStorage) one. Now the best option for you to remove model both from server and client is calling model's destroy method like that:

```
changetheme: function(value) {
    var modelToDelete = this.at(0) //take first model
    modelToDelete.destroy();
    this.create({theme:value});
}
```

Comment: This works and does not. Let me explain. I'm using local storage so when I use this.shift() it does remove my collection but next time around the collection is back to the full set. So say 1 item in collection, after I run the code I print out the length of collection it says 1. But when I reload its back up to 2. Its like localstorage does not clear out. Heres my code .http://jsbin.com/uyevag/1/watch

Comment: Thanks go this working, need another line before these three but working perfectly now. This is what I ended up with   this.fetch();
       var modelToDelete = this.at(0) //take first model
          modelToDelete.destroy();
          this.create({theme:value}); . Thanks for your help